# Double rendering for ReactJs component with Routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, rendering, react-router-dom

In reactJs, I used to work the following code to declare routes :

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

But I saw that it changed to this syntax

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

The problem is that I have a double rendering, the element `Home` is always rendering after the current component.

Here is my `App.js` :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/general-content/Header';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import TablesTest from './components/tables/TablesTest';
import TablesTestResults from './components/tables/TablesTestResults.jsx';

import Footer from './components/general-content/Footer';
import Error from  './components/general-content/Error';
import ThemeContext from './components/context/ThemeContext';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState("Brazil");

  const themeContext = {
    theme: theme,
    updateTheme: setTheme
  };

  return (
      <div className="App">
          <ThemeContext.Provider value={themeContext} >
                  <div className={theme}>
                      <BrowserRouter>
                          <Header />
                              <Routes>
                                  <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
                                  <Route path="/test" element={<TablesTest />} />
                                  <Route path="/test-results" element={<TablesTestResults />} />
                                  <Route path="/error" element={<Error />} />
                              </Routes> 
                              <Home />
                          <Footer />
                      </BrowserRouter>
                  </div>
          </ThemeContext.Provider>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank you for your support !

Comment: Hey, how did you detect the twice rendering ?
Just to ensure, maybe it's the twice rendering that caused by the StrictMode component by react to keep you coding safe and warn about stuff in the development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo: you should delete the `Home` component inside the `BrowserRouter`, but outside the `Route`, like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/test" element={<TablesTest />} />
        <Route path="/test-results" element={<TablesTestResults />} />
        <Route path="/error" element={<Error />} />
    </Routes>
    // <Home /> You have to delete this component, it is not required
    <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I don't know why this component was here ^^
But it's the reason while double rendering for sure

Comment: It happens, even to the best ;)